# Opencart, how to print ex tax amount on category view as like in product detail page?

Tags: opencart

Opencart, how to print ex tax amount on category view as like in product detail page? I tried with $price variable as like in product page, but it doesn't work in category page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:
`<?php echo $product['price']; ?>`

To:
`<?php echo $product['tax']; ?>`